# Web High Availability with pfSense

Tags: high-availability, pfsense

I am setting up a handful of servers in a co-location facility behind a pfSense firewall. We've decided for redundancy and high availability concerns to also have a duplicate set of servers in a second location. At both locations I have a single IP address and pfSense firewalls. As my background is in software engineering and not networking, how do I set this up in a way that if one firewall or facility goes off-line the other will take over? We have the ability to get a private ethernet connection between the facilities. The two locations are on different subnets. I hope I've supplied enough information.

Comment: You hve multiple way to do that, but it require something else. A way I use to know is a product that control your DNS and when it detect a down it switch the host in the DNS to direct to the correct datacenter (and your DNS name is setupped with a short TTL)

Comment: I've thought about that, and I'm currently checking with our registrar to see if they have a API I could use to make that change. I was looking for some other suggestions.

Comment: or just use round-robin if both datacenter can accept the load

Comment: are you referring to a round-robin DNS?